# To create a Tendermint Private LAN BlockChain and access it

Tags: android, tendermint

I am working on a review submission project on Tendermint in Windows. 
I want to submit a tamper-proof review about a organisation and hence want to create a private block-chain network with no validators and say 5 users, who submit their review via android app through abci-cli to the private blockchain. 
Can anyone guide me how to proceed with this. I am new to this whole topic and very confused about where to start.
I got this [How to create a Tendermint local network with same ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776159/how-to-create-a-tendermint-local-network-with-same-ip)
but want to run say 5 user accounts from different mobiles and Tendermint on 1 laptop(to create Blockchain). What I want to build is possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to create a tamper-proof review system, **you'll need as many validators as you can have, not just one**. You need them because it's straightforward to hack one validator and exploit your system. But if you have many validators, it's not so easy (given they are independent - different data centers, racks, ..). The whole power of blockchains emerges from having a large number of separate machines which can't easily be hacked.

Second, **you can have as many users as you want** (of course, there is an upper limit on how many txs per second Tendermint can process).

Third, **it's better if you use native Android API to send transactions**. Tendermint has 3 HTTP endpoints for transactions (https://tendermint.github.io/slate/#broadcasttxsync).

Comment: Thank you for your reply . we are facing problem in linking this four parts (client interface(android application) -> tendermint core->abcli-cli application(on eclipse)->application logic) we followed the documentation of tendermint on git but not properly explained how to do connection in between. This image will get to my point what i want to say
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LNrz.png

Comment: You will need 1) http client, who will be sending txs to Tendermint 2) ABCI application, written in any lang you want https://tendermint.readthedocs.io/en/master/app-development.html

Comment: Just one query, what ip address to call from android http client? is it localhost:46657 (default address of tendermint application, laptop and mobile connected to same network). and if we run our own ABCI application say on eclipse, how does it connects to tendermint core i.e. do we have to do anything on this part?

Comment: The IP address of the machine where Tendermint core is running. Client should actually store a few IPs and, if one IP stops responding, resend txs to other instance. By default, Tendermint core will try to connect to `tcp://localhost:26658`.